# react-router v6 removes useHistory, but useNavigate misses implementation

Tags: typescript, react-router, electron, react-router-dom

I have a scenario where we have a CustomHistory object, it's a hack in an electron application, so that certain routes are not stored in the history.

Previously we would use

```
const customHistory = useHistory() as CustomHistory;
```

This history object was provided to the router.
Is it no longer possible to access this through useNavigate?

Likewise, the history object would provide canGo(x) which would return a boolean. The useNavigate does not provide this functionality. I.e. to disable navigation buttons within an electron app. I wasn't able to find this in the migration documentation or the v6 documentation.